# Use a keyword in dynamic context in C#

Tags: c#, dynamic

```
dynamic json = new JsonObject();
json.ref.lolCats = GetLolCats();
```

gives me:

**Identifier expected; 'ref' is a keyword**

is there a way to escape the keyword using the dynamic syntax?

(so no `json["ref"].lolCats` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`ref` is used for `reference parameters`. It is a protected keyword. Try using another var name or append @ character before ref.

You can declare variables that use reserved keywords using the @:

```
private string @int;
```